# Bash script generating error while trying to append text to a file

Tags: file, bash, append

I am trying to make a simple bash script which prints out the path of current song in MPD.

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    mpc idle
    track=$(mpc current | awk -F " - " '{print $2}')
    echo $track

    path_to_track=$(mpc search title "$track")
    echo $path_to_track

    "$path_to_track" >> /home/noob/MPDPlaylist/testplaylist.m3u

done
```

Now, the problem is as soon as my script tries to appenf the value of `path_to_track` to the file it generates the below error

```
player
Skin To Bone
Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/09 - Linkin Park - Skin To Bone.mp3
test.sh: line 8: Linkin Park/Living Things(2012)/09 - Linkin Park - Skin To Bone.mp3: No such file or directory
```

Now, what am I doing wrong here. As you can see in the above code I already tried adding `double quotes` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you're trying to *execute* your mp3 files. You probably wanted to `echo` that:

```
echo "$path_to_track" >> /home/noob/MPDPlaylist/testplaylist.m3u
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Actually I tried it with `echo` but it was not working may be I messed something.